# Recursive function default mutable arguments

Tags: python

Let's say you have the function: `def f(..., visited= set())`.

Inside, you call `f()` again.

In this recursive call, if you don't pass visited, will create a new visited set()?

Comment: No, it will keep the same set. This is a common mistake. Just use `None` as a default and initialize a new empty set if `visited is None`.

Comment: Do you understand the behaviour in general: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1132941/least-astonishment-and-the-mutable-default-argument If so. why would you expect a recursive call to behave any differently from any other function call?

Answer (score 1):

No. The default argument is processed **only once** when the `def` statement is first run. So if you don't pass another argument for `visited`, the same set gets reused and can often lead to unexpected results.

From the [Python documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/controlflow.html#default-argument-values):

> The default values are evaluated **at the point of function definition** in the *defining* scope, so that ...

as well as the **Important warning** below.

> The default value is evaluated only once. This makes a difference when the default is a mutable object such as a list, dictionary, or instances of most classes. For example, the following function accumulates the arguments passed to it on subsequent calls:

Comment: `For example, the following function accumulates the arguments passed to it on subsequent calls:` What function?